# Building an embeddable React widget

Tags: reactjs, typescript, widget, embed

So I have a checkout UI which I built but I want users who don't necessarily have an account on my platform to be able to use this checkout just by embedding a script to their website. When they copy this code on their website,they get the checkout UI and they can use it.
they'll have two options of what checkout UI they want to use, one is a popup with the form for checking out, the other will just be on a page in their site.

the script will be something like this

```
<script defer="defer" src="https://janedoe.webfever.com/checkout/cc.js"></script>
<sc-checkout product="zero-to-one" subdomain="themarv" coupon=""></sc-checkout>
```

how do i achieve this, i've checked many resources, I didn't see any to help me.

I've not really tried anything cos I've never built a widget and the resources I see online don't do what I want

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a thing called **webcomponents**, you can learn all about it from https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction,

Here is the guide on how you can create it with react app, https://www.bitovi.com/blog/how-to-create-a-web-component-with-create-react-app.

I have not created a webcomponent but used this https://github.com/educastellano/qr-code/tree/gh-pages in one of my apps.

Hope it helps to give you a different direction.